# Using WebView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

recently I started creating an Android app with WebView. The app has grown and I changed the activity with WebView to tabbed activity using fragments and ViewPager. And there started my issue. After some headaches I finally managed how to display proper fragments for each tab. Then I simply copied the code for WebView to one of the fragment but the fragment isn't showing the web page I want. Any help will be appreciated!

Here's the code:

fragment with webView

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mWebView = (WebView) mWebView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("google.com");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bugtracker, container, false);
    }
}
```

and xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tabs$BugtrackerFragment">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Duggu how is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Things to do like

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bugtracker, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but I don't understand one thing, why is defining and returning `v` something else than just returning the definition of it?

Comment: 'v' denote here the View which is inflate.  that is user defined variable.