# Android (Java) - cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid:

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I trying to make an android app with two fragments, each with a webview window

The first one in the my MainActivity class

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_today);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    Log.wtf("System.out", "Open VPToday");
    mWebView.loadUrl("myLink");
```

And the second in the fragment class

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_morgen, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview_tomorrow);

    webView.loadUrl("myLink2");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

But on every start I get the warning "W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: [Some numbers]" and when I go to the fragment, I see a white fragment and get this warnings in logcat instantly:

```
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 7647
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
I/cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
W/cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 7647
```

Comment: [Android Webview: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33083066/6521116)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem, after I moved the first webview into a fragment 
And used this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31159185/6765618

in both fragments